# SQL find all homologous categories

Tags: mysql, sql, cross-join

I have a many-to-many relation between Category and Item, which is implemented with the "category_item" table, having 2 columns (PK): `category_id` and `item_id`.

Two homologous categories have the same items (order is not relevant):

```
A
  1
  2
```

is homologous to

```
B
  1
  2
```

but is not to

```
C       D       E
  1       1       1
  3               2
                  3
```

## Given a category id, how can I find all homologous categories?

---

Suppose this data in `item_category`:

```
A   1
A   2
B   1
B   2
C   1
C   3
D   1
E   1
E   2
E   3
```

I want to find all categories homologous to `A` (the expected result is just `B`)

I'm currently trying something like:

```
select r2.category_id
from category_item r1, category_item r2
where r1.category_id = ?
    and r2.category_id <> r1.category_id
    and r1.item_id = r2.item_id
```

that builds the table:

```
A   1   B   1
A   1   C   1
A   1   D   1
A   1   E   1
A   2   B   2
A   2   D   2
A   2   E   2
```

but I don't know how to continue...

---

I'm using MySQL 5.7, but I'd like to do it with just generic SQL.

*note that this is not a homework (also I don't think any teacher will assign such a complex one), it's just a extra-simplified use case for a real world problem*

Comment: provide sql fiddle please and provide expected resultset. your explanation is not clear to me

Comment: sqlfiddle.com is unreachable at the moment. Do you know an alternative site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it using subqueries and `exists`/ `not exists`

```
Select Distinct category_id 
from category_item ci
Where not exists   -- this allows only cats that do not have all req items
      (select * from category_item
       Where category_id = ci.category_id 
         and item_id Not in 
            (Select item_id from category_item
             Where category_Id = @catId))
  and not exists   -- this filters out cats that have xtra items
      (Select * from category_item
       Where category_Id = @catId
          and item_id Not in
            (Select item_id from category_item
             Where category_Id = ci.category_Id )) 
  and category_Id <> @catId -- <- categoryId of category you are matching
                            -- this line filters out the category you are 
                            -- matching against. Remove it if you want all
                            -- homologous categories
```

EXPLANATION:

`Select All distinct`Category_Id`s from the join table where:
  First subquery: 
        where there is not another join table row for that same category
        with an`Item_id`that is *not* in the set of`Item_id`s 
        for the category you are matching against, and
   Second subquery:
        where there is not an item in the category you are matching against
        that is not also in the category you are selecting (ci table)`

Comment: whoa! gimme some minute to recover myself and some hour to understand ;)

Comment: It seems it's not working: always returns empty results; but I've not totally methabolized it yet, so I'm executing it blindly

Comment: I'll set it up and test it here... there may be a typo or something ...

Comment: Yes, I was missing one predicate in the first subquery. Please try it again.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a [Group_Concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and then group by?

```
select ColA, group_concat(ColB order by ColB separator '|') as concat_line
from CategoryItem
group by ColA
```

You can then compare this to itself if you park it somewhere.

Comment: this seems a good way, but I'd prefer a standard one since I'm using JPA on top of MySQL and I don't like to use db-specific functions 'cause it induces a hard dependency (db would not be interchangeable without code refactorings)

Comment: @MicheleMariotti I don't think you can find good DB independent solution for your case.

Comment: @MicheleMariotti This is one of those situations where each DBMS uses a different function for the same thing, and this is the thing you need.

Comment: I don't agree. DBMS specific functions are just shortcuts. There's no query that can't be expressed with just plain old relational algebra.

Comment: the dbms-specific functions exist usually because doing that specific function with pure std syntax is somehow costly (slow, etc.).  you can do this with standard syntax, but standardization will require compromising something else, and that may or may not be acceptable